# Should you deflate prices by index when doing multiple regression?

Tags: regression

I have data ranging from 2008 - 2016. I have been studying effects on the %satisfaction of creditors in debt relief (Czech Republic). I have used modified "One vs. All" method, where I forgo the maximalisation step of P and evaluate the size of effects using the underlying models. In this case I use 4 models where the explained variable changes depending on the satisfaction group (ie. 4 groups of satisfaction).

The model I have used is something like this:

```
Y = debt + income + sex + marital status + age + ... (total 13 explanatory variables)
```

I could see inflation playing big role if I predicted time series or just maybe used debt or income to predict %satisfaction (simple regression), but I don't think inflation plays considerable role in model when I am predicting in space instead of predicting in time. The data supports that claim. I have rerun the whole model using deflated debt and income and the outcome was the same (changes were within 0,001 range).

Am I completely wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! While you are running a statistical model, the real question seems to deal with inflation macroeconomics. Consequently, I am not sure this question is on-topic here and perhaps should be moved to the Economics Stack.